# How do I access ffmpeg stdout as a buffer stream in node js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, buffer, stdout

I'm trying to access the output of an ffmpeg command (run with `spawn` in nodeJS) so that I can store the processed video in a buffer.

I've tried the following code:

```
(videoBuffer = [Unit8Array])

let arr = [];

let ffmpegSpawn = spawn(ffmpegPath, [
    "-i",
    "-",
    "-filter:v",
    "crop=500:500:50:50",
    "-preset",
    "fast",
    "-f",
    "mp4",
    "-",
  ]);

  ffmpegSpawn.stdin.write(videoBuffer);
  ffmpegSpawn.stdin.end();

  ffmpegSpawn.stdout.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    arr.push(chunk)
  });

  ffmpegSpawn.stderr.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  ffmpegSpawn.stdout.on("close", () => {
    console.log(arr)
  });
```

No error is being produced but I can't see any output in the console other than an empty array.

The ffmpeg command is successfully receiving the input via `child_process.stdin` and the `[ "-i", "-" ...]` args because I'm able to successfully create a test .mp4 file by passing the following args into ffmpeg (using spawn) :

```
[
    "-i",
    "-",
    "-filter:v",
    "crop=500:500:50:50",
    "-preset",
    "fast",
    "./desktop/testVideo.mp4"
  ]
```

I've tried accessing the child_process directly with:

```
ffmpegSpawn.on("data", (chunk) => { arr.push(chunk); console.log(chunk.toString()})
```

but nothing is seen on the console.

**Q: How do I access `ffmpegSpawn.stdout` ? As no error is being produced, I am assuming that the arguments to ffmpeg are valid.**

Why is the array empty ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stuck on `ffmpegSpawn.stdin.write(videoBuffer);` Move `on....` lines above the `write`. You need to set up the `stdout` events before sending in the first byte to `stdin`. Currently, there is a deadlock after the first few frames are written to `stdin`. Node.js is trying to send more frames but FFmpeg won't take them until its output data is read from `stdout`.

Another thing that'll bite you. You cannot use `mp4` container for piping the media data. MP4 requires the muxer (writer) to be able to seek the file, which you cannot do with pipe. Use alternate format. I know `-f matroska` would work.

Comment: Many Thanks Kesh. The heads up about MP4 was really helpful !!
The console prints a whole bunch of gibberish but it's working.

Ultimately I want to be able to store in MP4 format (as a Blob). Presumably I can just convert the buffer ?

Comment: The only problem is that the buffer is empty.

Comment: my knowledge on node.js is old so it's better to do your own research there. as for generating mp4, if that is your absolute end-goal, just let ffmpeg output to a temp mp4 file and read it when it's done encoding. Imho, more headache than its worth to try to fight it.